# Black screen (without cursor) displays after login to Unity 8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, mir, unity8

When log to Unity 8 mir on Ubuntu 16.04, A black screen displays on the screen without the cursor. (black screen only. No any other things)
I'm using open source graphics drivers.
I need to use Unity 8. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue when logging into Ubuntu GNOME, my issues was resolved by:

When you reach the black screen upon login, you could try pressing 'Ctrl + Alt + F1' and blindly type your username, press enter and then type your password. Press enter after this and a CLI environment should be displayed similar to a normal terminal.

From here, enter the command: `startx` which should start the unity 8 desktop environment.

Comment: But there are some other errors in Unity 8. However your code is working. Thank you @T3CHI5

Comment: How does that work? Unity 8 uses Mir not X?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt autoremove unity8

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt purge unity8 ubuntu-system-settings

sudo reboot and login in unity 7 (default)
```

I was in similar situation like you . unity 8 still in development stage . so try later .